# jQuery and CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the past I used the following code to take the take the text in the data-placeholder attribute and use it as a placeholder text for my div.

```
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content:attr(data-placeholder)
}
```

This worked great, but in my current project we need to do the same thing except it's entirely built using jQuery. I know jQuery has `.empty()`, `.before()`, `:not()`, and `.focus()` functions. With the way the jQuery selectors work, is it possible to use the CSS selector in the jQuery selector like so?

```
var div = $([contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before);
```

If not, then is there a better way to do this when working with so many functions?

Comment: You can't use `:before` and `:after` in jQuery. They're not real elements.

Comment: What are you trying to do? what's the purpose of selecting these elements?

Comment: @Amit I'm trying to take the CSS above and recreate it using jQuery so that we can continue to use this in our project.

Comment: Also, jQuery can't automatically react to attribute changes like `contenteditable`.

Comment: You need to redesign the application. Add a span before the contenteditable elements. When you add `contenteditable=true`, copy `.data('placeholder')` into the span.

Comment: You really can't use CSS in your project? Sounds like a nightmare come true.

Comment: @Juhana the project is a JavaScript library. So any CSS in the project is just used for the examples.

Comment: You can do it like jQuery UI -- the library requires you to use their CSS file.

Comment: @Barmar surely there's a way to do it without redesigning the application. I mean this is a div after all.

Comment: @Barmar It's not my project I'm just a contributor so I'm trying to stay consistent with the way the project currently is.

Comment: I can think of how to do the DOM changes in jQuery, but not how to trigger it. jQuery requires you to put the code in event handlers, but there's no event that happens just because an element is empty and doesn't have the focus.

Comment: You could run the code in `focus` and `blur` handlers, so it will add and remove the placeholder when the user moves into and out of the element.

Comment: Since I'm trying to work with a div that will ALWAYS have the data-placeholder attribute could I use a selector like this `$(div[data-placeholder])`

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. what is the purpose of the selection? suppose you have a div (or list of divs), what do you want to do with them? (keep in mind, as Barmar explained, this will be a static list / element, it won't react to anything)

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted The issue isn't with the selector. The CSS will dynamically change the content whenever the `focus` or `empty` state of the element changes. You need to hook into those state changes somehow, so your jQuery code will run.

Comment: @Barmar I can easily use jQuery's on function to hook into those states, but that isn't going to do me any good if I can't select the correct element.

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a way to allow for placeholder text in the div using a data-placeholder attribute.

Comment: Why can't you select the correct element? Just take out `:before`, and it will select the element. Then you can use `.before()` to add an element before it with the placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is to append a style tag:

```
var rule ='[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {'+
   ' content:attr(data-placeholder)'+
'}';
$('head').append('<style>'+rule +'</style>');
```